# Is there any command to get iOS device logs? Like using logcat we can get Android device logs

Tags: java, xcode, logging, appium, appium-ios

I am automating the iOS device using Appium and Java.

I wanted to get some ID from the logs and by using that ID I will fetch some data from Database.

This same thing done for Android device by using Logcat command and saved in Text file.

Is there any command or method to get iOS devices logs.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [idb](https://github.com/facebook/idb/blob/master/README.md) to get iPhone logs and more.
See official [docs](https://www.fbidb.io/docs/installation) for installation and usage instructions.